# Change Access form fields based on combo box choice

Tags: ms-access, field

I have an access form where users enter data for a record.

There is a status field that has a combo box with certain values and What I want to happen is that when option 2 is selected, some of the fields change.

For example:

```
field1, field2 and field3 exist / are visible by default (with option1)
user chooses option2
field1, field2 and field3 are replaced with field4, field5 and field6
```

I understand that this is a case of hiding fields 1, 2 and 3 and showing fields 4, 5 and 6 but I don't know how to implement this - how can it be done?

**EDIT:**

Johnny Bones's answer is correct, but it brought to my attention another behaviour that I wasn't aware of.

First of all, the code works correctly and the correct fields disappear and appear as expected.  However, what I didn't realise would happen is that the newly-visible fields (under `Option2` that appeared for `record1`), remain visible for all other records when I navigate away from `record1`.

How do I set up the system so that, when a user navigates to a new record, `field1`, `field2` and `field3` are displayed as normal and `field4`, `field5` and `field6` are hidden (which is / should be the default view).

How can this be achieved?

**UPDATE:**

I solved the problem - I added some code on the form's `OnCurrent` property to read whatever the value is in the `Options` field and to display and hide each `field` value accordingly.

Comment: I don't know if OnCurrent solves this, but you need similar logic in the OnLoad event too.  Not an If/Then, but just 6 statements telling which should be visible and which shouldn't.  Otherwise, when you first launch the page, all 6 will be visible.  Again, OnCurrent *may* solve that but I just wanted to bring it up.

Comment: I tried this, but it isn't quite what I need as each record will have an `Option` specific to that record, and if it is `Option2`, then I need `fields` 4, 5 and 6 visible by default for that specific record.

Comment: I suppose you can force it to default to Option 1, and then set the visibilities based on what they should be if Option 1 was selected.  OR, in the OnLoad set their Enabled state to False.  This way they can't enter anything in the boxes anyway.  In the AfterUpdate event of the dropdown, set all of them back to Enabled = True.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but to be honest the `If/Then` works best for my particular needs here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really have 2 options here, it depends on how your form is set up.  You can either make some visible and others not visible, or just use 3 generic boxes.  If your form is bound to a table, you're stuck with option 1.  If it's not bound (which, IMO, is the proper way to do it because it gives you *much* more flexibility), you can use either one.

If your form is bound, you just need to add some code in the AfterUpdate event of the dropdown:

```
If Me.MyDropdownName.Value = "Option 2" Then
  Me.txtTextbox1.Visible = False
  Me.txtTextbox2.Visible = False
  Me.txtTextbox3.Visible = False
  Me.txtTextbox4.Visible = True
  Me.txtTextbox5.Visible = True
  Me.txtTextbox6.Visible = True
Else
  Me.txtTextbox1.Visible = True
  Me.txtTextbox2.Visible = True
  Me.txtTextbox3.Visible = True
  Me.txtTextbox4.Visible = False
  Me.txtTextbox5.Visible = False
  Me.txtTextbox6.Visible = False
Endif
```

All you have to do is lay Textbox4 directly on top of Textbox1, Textbox5 directly on top of Textbox2 and Textbox6 directly on top of Textbox3.

If the form is unbound, then you would add code that first checks the value of the dropdown and then writes the value inside the textboxes to the appropriate fields.